# How to save captured image from camera in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera2, android-file, android-external-storage

The [official sample](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Basic) of Camera2Basic for capturing images from camera.
It only shows the captured image in an activity but does not save the image to external storage

How to save that image to external storage?

I searched **a lot** over the internet for this, but there are all of the deprecated as of Android 11 (API 30).
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the code specifically for saving images in Android 11?

Comment: And by saying external storage do you mean to refer to SD card?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility) could help :D

Comment: Use `private suspend fun saveResult()`. This is one of the functions in the source you quoted. ;-)

Comment: _Do you want the code specifically for saving images in Android 11?_ @AbhishekChoudhary, yes.. and yes, I mean SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use camerax lib from google which is part android jetpack

Comment: Thank you!
That worked for me....the official sample for CameraX is very useful